# How to create Form filter in angular application?

Tags: angular, form-control

I want to make a filter with 2 main type input are text and Date type, i create array

```
arr = [1,2,3]
```

it's number of filter's row. But when i for loop and then change label to *dateOfBirth*, all input row changed.

my template file:

```html
  <form [formGroup]="searchAdvanceForm">
            <div class="filter" *ngFor="let item of filterRow; let i= index;">
              <div>{{i + 1}}</div>
              <ng-select [items]="fieldFilter" bindLabel="label" bindValue="value" placeholder="---Choose---"
                         [closeOnSelect]="true" [clearable]="true" formControlName="field{{i}}">
              </ng-select>

              <input *ngIf="searchAdvanceForm.controls.field0.value !== 'dateOfBirth'" class="textFilter" type="text"
                     formControlName="valueSearch{{i}}">

              <nz-date-picker *ngIf="searchAdvanceForm.controls.field0.value === 'dateOfBirth'"
                              [nzFormat]="dateFormat" formControlName="valueSearchDate{{i}}"></nz-date-picker>

              <ng-select [items]="operatorFilter" bindLabel="label" bindValue="value" placeholder="---Choose---"
                         [closeOnSelect]="true" formControlName="operatorSearch{{i}}"></ng-select>
            </div>
  </form>
```

and here is my UI when normal
[image: normal]

and when i choose **Date of Birth** field, the form will like this
[image: bug]

> I expect when i choose **Date of birth** just this row change type input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only referencing `controls.field0` but you want to reference the control on the same row.

```html
<input *ngIf="searchAdvanceForm.get('field' + i).value !== 'dateOfBirth'" ... />

<nz-date-picker
  *ngIf="searchAdvanceForm.get('field' + i).value === 'dateOfBirth'"
  ...
></nz-date-picker>
```

Comment: IT WORK, I really thank you, I know i have to get the identification number but don't know how, you save my sleep tonight, it's 2:10 am here